# Raspberry Pi and Buzzers: Simple solution

Tags: raspberry-pi, electronics

I have a Raspberry Pi 1 Model A and am interested in attaching a buzzer to its GPIO pins so that the software (running on the pi) can turn the buzzer on/off by sending signals to the GPIO pins.

I'm new to electronics so I'm looking for the simplest setup possible. I watched [this Youtube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6rbgsIRun1o) where the author just plops a buzzer down into a breadboard and uses jumper wires to connect the breadboard/buzzer to the pi's GPIO pins. I'd like a similar (simple!) setup.

I'm wondering what the make/model/specs are for that buzzer so that I can buy the same one and attach it to my pi/breadboard the exact same way (or if there's a simpler way out there, I'm open to that as well!). Any ideas what the voltage/amperage ratings would need to be so as to be compatible with the pi (without the need for additional things like circuit drivers, resistors, transistors, etc.)? Remember, I'm a total newb here and simpler == better!

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Anyone? Bueller?! Anybody ever used a buzzer before?

Comment: Y'all can't migrate a question from another SE site (an action that I had no control over) and then mark this as a dupe. If you call this a dupe, you're a dope!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For a beginner, it is always best to follow / copy an existing example.  Fortunately, a tutorial about connecting a sound device to a Raspberry Pi and parts are available [here](https://learn.adafruit.com/piezo-ring-tones-with-raspberry-pi). Also, there is a [Raspberry Pi Stackexchange web site](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com) (should you have more Raspberry Pi questions).

Any device connected to an embedded processor must operate at the voltages the embedded processor is operating at and must not draw more current than the embedded processor can supply safely.  The voltage and current ratings of the Raspberry Pi's GPIO pins are discussed [here](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/9298/what-is-the-maximum-current-the-gpio-pins-can-output).

The above tutorial is more complex than a simple buzzer.  As it appears to be able to play music.  But the tutorial is complete and physically it does not appear any more complex than the circuit in the youtube video linked to in the question.  Rather, the complexity is in the software which likely can just be downloaded and used.

Comment: Thanks so much for all the great help @st2000 (+1) - however...I don't see the make/model/specs (voltage/current ratings, etc.) for the piezo buzzer in that Adafruit link you posted. **Any ideas?!** (I'm not comfortable moving forward without knowing what "natively works" with my model pi...I fried an Arduino a few months ago hooking it up to servos and I don't want the same fate to befall my pi!) Thanks again so much!

Comment: I simply assumed it is the same device that is advertised in the right margin.  Clicking on that device takes me [here](https://www.adafruit.com/product/1740). Where I see: 
    Resonant Frequency: 8kHz
    Max Rated Current: 3.0mA
    Rated Voltage: 9V
    Operating Temperature: -20ºC ~ 70ºC
    Maximum Input Voltage: 40V

Comment: Thanks @st2000 (+1 again) - so if I'm reading that tutorial correctly, this buzzer is "natively compatible" (no need for circuit drivers, resistors, transistors, etc.) with my pi? Meaning if I wire it up to the breadboard and GPIO pins correctly, I shouldn't fry my board, yes? Thanks again!

Comment: Adafruit has been around for years and are well known.  I tend to trust their tutorials assuming they have been vetted by Adafruit and the community of users that contribute in the [Adafruit forums](https://forums.adafruit.com/).  Now that I look at the specifications, I assume this is just a bare piezoelectric sound device.  Not necessarily a self contained "buzzer" (a device that will make a noise when powered).

Comment: Ahh, glad I asked @st2000 (+1), so you're saying that this "piezo device" from the Adafruit tutorial won't actually make any noise when activated? If not, then any chance you can help me find one that does? Ideally I'd like to get it ordered this week!

Comment: The sound is created using the software. I have not looked deeply into this but the software likely modulates the processor's pin and causes the piezoelectric device to vibrate.  If you search for buzzer on the Adafruit site you will find several matches.  If you go to the 1st and scroll down you will find a complex Geofencing project which uses this buzzer.  In the Geofencing instructions Adafruit simply connects the buzzer to pin 9 of an Arduino and ground.